# Proceed to different view controllers based on boolean value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, tableview

When a table cell is selected, I am trying to proceed to a view controller if the value of a boolean is true, else (if it is false), proceed to a different view controller. Any help would be great!
(The boolean is isAdmin and if true proceed to eventViewController, else proceed to UserEventTableViewController)

link to project: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d4d8opuxzpcuk4/TicketekApp.zip?dl=0

Code:

```
import UIKit

class EventTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: Properties

var events = [Event]()
var isAdmin = false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    // Load any saved events, otherwise load sample data.
    if let savedEvents = loadEvents() {
        events += savedEvents
    } else {
        // Load the sample data.
        loadSampleEvents()
    }
}

func loadSampleEvents() {
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "event1")!
    let event1 = Event(name: "ACDC", photo: photo1, rating: 4, price: 500.0, eventDescription: "Album", album: "Album1")!

    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "event2")!
    let event2 = Event(name: "Cold Play", photo: photo2, rating: 5, price: 500.0, eventDescription: "Album", album: "Album1")!

    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "event3")!
    let event3 = Event(name: "One Direction", photo: photo3, rating: 3, price: 500.0, eventDescription: "Album", album: "Album1")!

    events += [event1, event2, event3]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return events.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "EventTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate event for the data source layout.
    let event = events[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = event.name
    cell.photoImageView.image = event.photo
    cell.ratingControl.rating = event.rating
    cell.priceLabel.text = event.album

    return cell
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want item to be editable.
    return true
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        events.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        saveEvents()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create new instance of  class, add to the array, and add a new row to the table
    }
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
// Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let eventDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EventViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedEventCell = sender as? EventTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedEventCell)!
            let selectedEvent = events[indexPath.row]
            eventDetailViewController.event = selectedEvent
            print(selectedEventCell)
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("Adding new event.")
    }
}


@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? EventViewController, event = sourceViewController.event {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing event.
            events[selectedIndexPath.row] = event
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new event.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: events.count, inSection: 0)
            events.append(event)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
        // Save the events.
        saveEvents()
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

func saveEvents() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(events, toFile: Event.ArchiveURL.path!)
    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save events...")
    }
}

func loadEvents() -> [Event]? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Event.ArchiveURL.path!) as? [Event]
}
}
```

Comment: `prepareForSegue` is too late to change the segue;  You need to link you segues from the UIViewController object in your scene and then implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` - in this method you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to invoke the desired segue based on whatever logic you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the tableView delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

example as follows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    //use the index to know which cell you selected

    //check for your condition here something like
    if isAdmin {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("eventViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("userEventTableViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

note the following:

1. In your story board, draw segues to the different view controllers and assign the segue ID respectively.
2. In your code you are not changing the value of isAdmin boolean. Check that too.

Regards.

Image on how to segue from ViewController for your reference
[image]

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie, but would I draw segues to a new view controller when the table cell is clicked and would one be an accessory selection?

Comment: I believe you can see accessory action only when you draw segue from your tableViewCell to the destinationViewController. Ideally you should draw manual segues from sourceViewController to destinationViewController

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish what you are seeking by using `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Add this to your view controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
```

and handle your logic within that function.

When you are ready to go to the next view controller, use

```
performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)
```

Here is an example:

```
if isAdmin {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToAdminView", sender: self)
} else {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "segueToUserEventView", sender: self)
}
```